# Data Management API Bucket Usage Cost/Limits

Tags: autodesk-forge

How much cost the storage usage of a bucket? There is a limit of objects that can be stored on it?

Answer (score 2):

The [pricing page](https://forge.autodesk.com/pricing) says that - with the trial subscription - the space limit (for all buckets in your Forge application) is 5GB. For paid subscriptions there is no space or usage limit.